# Can Bohr-Mollerup Theorem be extended to complex plane?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, gamma-function

There is a famous theorem says about Gamma function:

> *Bohr-Mollerup Theorem*
>
> Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a function satisfying below
>
> (i) $f(x+1)=xf(x), \forall x\in (0,\infty)$
>
> (ii) $f$ is a log-convex function
>
> (iii) $f(1)=1$
>
> Then, $f=\Gamma$ on its domain

This theorem only shows that the Gamma function deserves to be called the factorial function for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Is it possible to extend this idea to complex plane so Gamma function deserves to be the *best* factorial function?

Since $t^{z-1}e^{-t}$ can be decomposed into its real part and imaginary part using cosine&sine function, i guess it would show that the Gamma function on *complex plane* has some flexible property similar to that on *real line*.

Comment: How do you define convex for a complex-valued function?

Comment: Not answering but just wondering : so we could find a function which has property (i) and (iii) but not log-convex which is not the Gamma function ? I'm curious, do we have such an example ?

Comment: @Rivten: See e.g. http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html

Comment: @Martin Of course i'm not saying the complex Gamma function would have some *inequality property*. I just want to know how much the Gamma function is *smooth*(informally speaking) while the real part of it is very *smooth*.

Comment: I still dont't get your idea. In the complex plane one time differentiable=$C^\infty$=analytical.

Comment: @Martin As i said i didn't meab *smooth* to mean the definition of smooth in complex analysis. I just meant whether this function is extraordinarily more flexible than other substitutes *literally*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function of complex variable, $\Gamma$ is meromorphic. There is an *identity theorem*: if two meromorphic functions on $\mathbb C$ agree on a set with a limit point in $\mathbb C$, then they agree everywhere in $\mathbb C$. In particular, two meromorphic functions that agree on $(0,\infty)$ agree everywhere. As a consequence, any modification of $\Gamma$ away on  $\mathbb C\setminus (0,\infty)$ would lose the property of being meromorphic.

One can use the identity theorem to show that (i) continues to hold in the complex plane. Indeed, $\Gamma(z+1)$ and $z\Gamma(z)$ are two meromorphic functions that agree on $(0,\infty)$; as discussed above, this implies  $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. (Minor detail: at $z=0$ one should interpret the product on the right as the limit  $\lim_{z\to 0}z\Gamma(z) $.)

Answer (score 3):

A beautiful and simple characterization of the complex $\Gamma$-function exists. It is Wielandt's theorem where you just change condition (ii) "$f$ is a log-convex function" by "$f(x)$ is bounded in the strip $\{x\in\mathbb{C} \mid1\leq\Re(x)\leq2\}$". See Reinhold Remmert : [Wielandt's Theorem About the Γ-Function](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975370).